# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources' android studio, SugarORM

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, sugarorm

As per [Sugar ORM documentation](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/index.html) said I have used following line

when ever I use

```
compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.3'
```

in my Gradle it will look like:

```
  dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'
  }
```

when ever I use

```
compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.3'
```

in compilation time I am getting following error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/amit/android-sdk-linux_86/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

FAILED

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/amit/android-sdk-linux_86/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

but whenever **I remove it, it will build successfully,**

Can anybody help me if I want to use sugarORM how can I use it

Comment: can you post more detail about the stacktrace?  try to use gradlew assembleDebug --info

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti thank you so much for quick reply I am just updating question

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti i was just getting above only

Comment: I tried  compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.3' and the following happened:

1. First time got error while executing :app:processDebugManifest 

this was due to conflict with android icon in Manifest file

     android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
once I removed the icon from Manifest, i was able to build successfully. No issues with app:processDebugResources.

Comment: Might be an issue with the buildtools version. Can you provide your whole gradle file?